# SFINAE set of types contains the type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

I want to construct my class `class C` from each type in set of types `...T`. `sizeof...(T)` is large enough so that I did not want to write out all the constructor variants as below:

```
// T : {T1, T2, ..., TN}
struct C
{
    C(T1);
    C(T2);
    ...
    C(TN); // Phew! I'm tired.
};
```

So I want to try the next:

```
// type_set is something like template< typename... T > struct type_set {...};
struct C 
{
    using constructible_from_types = type_set< int, double, short >;
    template< typename T0 >
    C(T0, typename std::enable_if< is_contained< T0, constructible_from_types >::value >::type * = nullptr);
};
// or
// type_set is something like template< typename... T > struct type_set { template< typename T0 > constexpr bool is_contained() {...} ...}
struct C 
{
    using constructible_from_types = type_set< int, double, short >;
    template< typename T0 >
    C(T0, typename std::enable_if< constructible_from_types::is_contained< T0 >() >::type * = nullptr);
};
```

But I don't know how to implement the `is_contained` type trait and `type_set` class.

And, in general, interested in the canonical implementation of solution of this problem.

Comment: Does it need to be exactly that type, or only convertible?

Comment: And if convertible, how do you want to pick?

Comment: I want the set of constructors, each of which behaves as `explicit` one.

Comment: Also I want to create a set of `C&operator=(C&&)` and set of `C&operator=(C&)` by the same manner. So I define the corresponding `typedef` (via `using`).

Comment: @Dukales: That doesn't answer the question - `explicit` only says how `C` can be constructed, not if it can also be constructed from, say, `char`, which is convertible to `int`.

Comment: Ok, it need to be exactly a type from the set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, a better constructor:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<is_contained<T, T0, T1, T2>::value>
C(T) { }

// or C(T const &), or even C(T &&)
// and use "typename std::decay<T>::type" instead of just "T"
```

Now the trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename ...> struct is_contained : std::false_type { };

template <typename T, typename Head, typename ...Tail>
struct is_contained<T, Head, Tail...> : std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<T, Head>::value || is_contained<T, Tail...>::value> { };
```

To repeat, the usage is:

```
is_contained<T, double, int, char>::value
```

If you prefer wrapping the type list into another type, that's a simple modification, but I'd just use `std::tuple` as the wrapper type.

---

Following the comments, here's a constructor that takes a universal reference:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if<
              is_contained<typename std::decay<T>::type,
                           T0, T1, T2, T3>::value
                                   >::type>
C(T && t)
{  }
```

With even more magic you could even go through every element in your list and see if the constructor argument is *convertible* to the list item, but that may be different from what you want.

Comment: sure by `or even C(T &&)` you mean `C(typename std::remove_reference< T >::type &&)` (btw, I doubt that it's possible to use)?

Comment: @Dukales: No, the other way around. The deduced argument is `T`, but the thing you look up in your list should be the decayed version. Just as I say in the comment. Let me know if you want me to spell it out.

Comment: `template< typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< is_contained< T, type_set >::value > C(T &&) { ; }` Is `T` here an universal reference?

Comment: @Dukales: Yes, it is. Hence the need for decay.

Comment: Will it lead to the need to write an explicit type in angle brackets? And supress the deduction of argument type in expected manner?

Comment: @Dukales: I updated the answer to spell out how to use a universal reference.

Comment: I'm sure it will be useful not only to me

Comment: `template<class T, class... Ts> struct is_contained : std::is_constructible<identity<T>, inherit<identity<Ts>...>>{};` :3

Comment: `std::decay` may not be exactly you want, because it also decays `T(&)[N]` into `T*`, which is pretty lossy.  It is great for removing references and const and volatile, but I'm not sure if we'd want to decay functions into pointers-to-functions, and arrays into pointers...

Answer (score 1):

This traits class works on any package of types, be it `type_set` or `std::tuple`:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename L> struct is_contained; // illegal
template<typename T, template<typename...>class L>
struct is_contained< T, L<> > : std::false_type {};
template<typename T, template<typename...>class L, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct is_contained< T, L<T0, Ts...> > :
  std::integral_constant< bool,
    std::is_same<T, T0>::value
    || is_contained< T, L<Ts...> >::value
  >
{};
```

however, I find `index_of` more useful:

```
template<typename T, typename L, typename=void> struct index_of; // illegal
template<typename T, template<typename...>class L>
struct index_of< T, L<>, void > {}; // SFINAE enable
template<typename T, template<typename...>class L, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_of<
  T,
  L<T0, Ts...>,
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, T0>>::type
> : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 1 + index_of< T, L<Ts...> >::value >
{};
template<typename T, template<typename...>class L, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_of<
  T,
  L<T0, Ts...>,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, T0>>::type
> : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 0 >
{};
```

which also lets you check for existence via SFINAE as `index_of<T,List>::value` exists iff `T` is in the `List`.

Next, I'd enable perfect forwarding on the constructor:

```
template<typename T>
using RemoveRefCv = typename std::remove_cv< typename remove_ref< T >::type >::type;
struct C 
{
  using constructible_from_types = std::tuple< int, double, short >;
  template< typename T, std::size_t=std::index_of<RemoveRefCv<T0>>::value >
  C(T&&);
};
```

(assuming you don't want to have to worry about being constructable from the `const` but not the non-`const` in your list).

You can go a step further, and accept any `T` that is convertible to any of the types in your list.  This can require some intelligence in determining how you handle conflicts.  A simple method might be to find a perfect match, and failing that find the first one that you can be convertible.

If you look up at `index_of`, you'll note that it does most of its work by querying `std::is_same`.  You can write a `search_for` that takes the binary `bool`ean template as an argument, and looks for the first one in the list that matches.

```
template<template<typename, typename>class Func, typename T, typename L, typename=void> struct search_for; // illegal
template<template<typename, typename>class Func, typename T, template<typename...>class L>
struct search_for< Func, T, L<>, void > {}; // SFINAE enable
template<
  template<typename, typename>class Func,
  typename T,
  template<typename...>class L,
  typename T0,
  typename... Ts
>
struct search_for<
  Func,
  T,
  L<T0, Ts...>,
  typename std::enable_if<!Func< T, T0 >::value
> : std::integral_constant<
  std::size_t,
  1 + search_for< Func, T, L<Ts...> >::value
> {};
template<
  template<typename, typename>class Func,
  typename T,
  template<typename...>class L,
  typename T0,
  typename... Ts
>
struct search_for<
  Func,
  T,
  L<T0, Ts...>,
  typename std::enable_if<Func<T, T0>::value>::type
> : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 0 >
{};
template<template<typename,typename>class Func, typename T, typename L>
using SearchFor = search_for<Func, T, L>;
```

which I would then rewrite `index_of` in terms of:

```
template<typename T, typename List>
struct index_of:SearchFor<std::is_same, T, List> {};
```

Then write a class that tries `index_of`, and if that fails tries `search_for< std::is_constructable, ... >`, extracts that index, then uses that type to convert the passed in argument to that indexed type in your list:

```
template<std::size_t n, typename L>
struct get_type {};// SFINAE enabled
template<std::size_t n, template<typename...>class L>
struct get_type< n, L<> > {};
template<template<typename...>class L, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct get_type< 0, L<T0, Ts...> > {
  typedef T0 type;
};
template<std::size_t n, template<typename...>class L, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct get_type< n, L<T0, Ts...> >:
  get_type< n-1, L<Ts...> >
{};
template<std::size_t n, typename List>
using GetType = typename get_type<n, List>::type;
```

because if you don't do that, and your type is constructed from an `int` and someone passes in a `short` or an `unsigned int` or whatever, your SFINAE code will reject being constructed from something that isn't perfectly in your type list.