# Repeat template enable_if condition on multiple templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have the following code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename T, typename...>
struct is_contained : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct is_contained<T, Head, Tail...>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, Head>::value ||
                                       is_contained<T, Tail...>::value> {};

// Enum types
enum class Fruit { APPLE, BANANA };
 
// To string maps
std::map<Fruit, std::string> fruits = {{Fruit::APPLE, "apple"},
                                       {Fruit::BANANA, "banana"}};

// Map string map to enum
template <typename T>
std::map<T, std::string> typeMap;
template <>
std::map<Fruit, std::string> typeMap<Fruit> = fruits;

// operator<< for mapped enums
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<is_contained<T, Fruit>::value>>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const T &t) {
  os << typeMap<T>.at(t);
  return os;
}

int main() {
  Fruit f = Fruit::BANANA;
  std::cout << f << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

... to implement `operator<<` for various enum types. Now the specific line:

```
typename = std::enable_if_t<is_contained<T, Fruit>::value>>
```

makes sure that my stream operator implementation is only used for my specific type which would be expanded to a list of all of my user enum types.

The problem I am trying to solve is how to reuse that condition on other template functions without having to repeat the list of types or to use macros. Something like: `typename = TypeIsInMyList<T>`

Might be very simple, but I failed to come up with something.

*The `is_contained` implementation was found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252940/11722.*

Comment: If you're just trying to implement `operator<<` for various enums, why bother with the template at all?  Just implement `operator<<` for each type in turn, and place it in the same namespace as the type, and ADL will do the rest.

Comment: There will be more functions,  not just operator<< which is why i am looking for a reusable solution. Also  I am simply curious on how to solve this even if there are other approaches for better understanding of templates.

Comment: If I do need it, I tend towards a traits type that defines all of the related functions, as well as a `typedef std::integral_constant<bool, true> traits_defined`, and I use that typedef as part of the enable_if (the non-specialized version has the typedef set to false).  But again, if you're just disabling functions, I find that overloaded functions that uses the argument to be the 'cleaner' solution in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a simple `using`, like

```
template <typename T>
using TypeIsInMyList
   = std::enable_if_t<is_contained<T, Fruit, void, int, char>::value>;
```

that you can use as follows

```
template <typename T,
          typename = TypeIsInMyList<T>>
```

But I suggest to modify it as follows

```
template <typename T>
using TypeIsInMyList
   = std::enable_if_t<is_contained<T, Fruit, void, int, char>::value, int>;
```

and use it on the left of the equal

```
template <typename T,
          TypeIsInMyList<T> = 0>
```

It's a little complicated but... I don't think it's a real difference, in you case, but the second solution is the a preferable way when you have alternative function in overloading.

Comment: I prefer to use `std::nullptr_t` instead of `int`, this way user can't abuse your templates by passing some different value to the second argument.

Comment: Perfect, this works. I thought I had tried something similar but I must have messed it up somehow.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Interesting point... I'm not an expert, but I remember there are doubts regarding the legal use of `void *` as type for a template value, so... are you sure that `std::nullptr_t` is a valid type for a template value parameter?

Comment: @max66 I'm not sure, but GCC, Clang & MSVC all accept it. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - If I understand correctly, according to [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), should be a valid type... very interesting

Answer (score 4):

Here's the C++20 way of doing things:

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
concept one_of = (std::same_as<T, P> || ...);
```

Then you can either directly write this:

```
template <one_of<Fruit, void, int, char> T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const T &t) {/*...*/}
```

Or make yet another concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept foo = one_of<T, Fruit, void, int, char>;

template <foo T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const T &t) {/*...*/}
```

Comment: Will definitely use concepts when I can, still on C++17.

Comment: @Zitrax Then you can at least rewrite `is_contained` using a fold expression. Something like `template <typename T, typename ...P> constexpr bool is_contained = (std::same_as<T, P> || ...);`.